# (Spring cloud config server) Loading configuration other than pattern {application}/{profile}

Tags: spring-cloud-config

In https://github.com/shauank/spring-cloud/tree/master/spring-cloud-prop, how to read property value from *email-conf.properties*.

Assuming: spring.application.name=reservation and profile=default.
As per convention spring cloud will load *reservation.properties* and *application.properties*. But I wanted to load *email-conf.properties* also. How to achieve?

Comment: Provide what all you have tried

Comment: Tried with following configuration, 
  `spring:
          application:
          name: reservation
    cloud:
     config:
      profile: ${env}`
  Also tried with(active profile) 
  `... 
    profiles:
    active: production 
 .... 
   spring.profiles: production
   spring.profiles.include:
     - email-conf`.  
  
  If  _${env}_ is _production_, then config server loads, _reservation.properties_, _reservation-production.properties_, _*reservation-email-conf.properties*_  and _application.properties_. But I wanted to load _email-conf.properties_ .

Answer (score 2):

See [the doc of cloud config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_serving_plain_text), access the endpoint `/{name}/{profile}/{label}/{path}` for plain text file.

In your case, you can get the content of `email-conf.properties` via url `/reservation/default/master/email-conf.properties`.