# Spring cloud config - loading additional files

Tags: java, spring, properties-file, spring-cloud-config

I got a spring cloud server for my applications, serving the common property files at startup.

The 'normal' functionality is working fine. An application fetches the hierarchy of files and got the full access to the loaded parameters.

```
Application.properties
Application-<profile>.properties
<applicationname>.properties
...
```

Now the question:
How can I load a configuration file beside the common naming?

If I am storing another file in repositoy e.g. sharedCommonServers.properties, how can I load this file in addition using the config server?
This file contains properties used by some but not all programs.

Thank you in advance!

Hendrik

Comment: `@PropertySource("classpath:sharedCommonServers.properties")`, just add it to your application class.

Comment: The sharedCommonServers.properties should be loaded using the cloud config server. I added your line to the configuration, but it doesn't seem to load it. Is it right, this line would load the file only from local storage, or should it use the config server, too?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41374808/390513), it should be helpful.

Comment: @Kane Yes, that is what I'm currently investigating. Not really a solution out of the box, but maybe a good attempt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, at least I found a solution:

I took the normal application-context of cloud config.
Within this context I placed my file *sharedCommonServers.properties* as a default application property file with a special profile.

Renaming:

```
'sharedCommonServers.properties' to 'application-commonServers.properties'
```

By extending the profile settings with 'commonServers' spring cloud config is fetching it in addition.

Take care there are no overlapping property-keys in the other profile-line.

So in my environment when I set...

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=prod,commonServers'
```

...I get my default prod configuration and those marked as 'commonServers' profiles.

```
application.properties
application-prod.properties
application-commonServers.properties // the additional one
<appname>.properties
<appname>-prod.properties
// and <appname>-commonServers.properties if I would need it
```

Thank you for your suggestions and thoughts!